# How to replace an if statement with an alternative?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In an article titled [Rethinking JavaScript: The if statement](https://dev.to/joelnet/rethinking-javascript-the-if-statement-9cg), it says:

> I have recently been questioning the if statement itself.
>
> Having written an entire application completely void of a single if statement, I have found if to be optional.

I would like to understand how to replace this code:

```js
  if (value <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
```

with a non-if alternative, as the article suggests.

The first suggestion in the article is a ternary operator:

```js
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

The article suggests that "*almost every instance of an if statement could be replaced with an equivalent ternary operation*", but this could not replace my code - it would replace an `if else` statement, not an `if`.

Another article by the same author, [Functional Programming: Alternatives to the IF](https://dev.to/joelnet/functional-programming-how-would-you-if-no-else-javascript-59ai), says:

> This function has an if statement without an else. So while a ternary operator could work, it is not ideal.
> ...
> One option is to use a short circuit operator:
>
> ```js
> item && dispatch({ type: 'ACTION', item })
> ```

This however does not replace my code because I get a linting error: `Expression expected.` - This is correct - it is enforcing correct use of logical operators.

I tried a logical operator like this:

```js
const maxValue = (value <= 0) && 0;
return maxValue;
```

But this does not replace the `if` statement because the function that the `if` statement is in must return a number, and this returns `'false | 0'`.

So my question is, how do I follow the article's advice and replace the if statement with an alternative?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to replace it? It's perfectly fine code.

Comment: you could replace it by ``return value <= 0 ? 0 : null``

Comment: You can't replace that specific `if` because of the `return` part

Comment: You can do this, if the rest of your function fits in the second part of that ternary expression. To help you with that, we need the code of the rest of the function as well. But really, unless the rest of the function is a very simple return statement, you should just follow what Andy said.

Comment: Could you provide more context to your question? What's the surrounding code, what does the function do?

Comment: @Tracer69 Why `null` and not `undefined` or `-1` or `false` or `NaN` or ... A function that returns in one case a number and in the other a totally unrelated type of value should ring your alarm bells.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function that doesn't return anything, like so:

```
function foo() {}
```

then the implicit return value is `undefined`.

If, and only if, there is nothing *after* your if statement, then you *could* use a ternary operator to return undefined:

```
return (value <= 0) ? 0 : undefined;
```

However, this ***is not*** a true replacement for your code.

A ternary operator doesn't just replace an if/else expression. It replaces a *very specific **kind*** of if/else, where each alternative neatly returns a single value.

For example, given:

```
var x = condition ? expr1 : expr2;
```

The if/else syntax would look like this:

```
var x;
if (condition) x = expr1; else x = expr2;
```

If there is more advanced logic in your if/else block, or if the else block is missing entirely, than a ternary operator is not appropriate and should typically be avoided in favor of clarity.

Answer (score -1):

You could take [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), which returns either a value greater than zero or zero if smaller.

```
return Math.max(value, 0);
```

Comment: The (non-existent) `else` case in the source doesn't have a `return` statement. And even so, I think the core of this question isn't about a shortcut for the `<=`, but about a shortcut for the whole `if` statement...

Comment: but in the second code part is a return statement without `if`.

Comment: From the OP: _"However this could not replace my code - it would replace an `if else` statement, not an `if`."_

Comment: Are you saying the OP is trying to replace `if (value <= 0) {return 0} return value`? I didn't see that

Comment: It once again boils down to a question being vague, and requiring more input from the OP before being answered.

Comment: Math.max is also just an expression, pretty much working the same as a ternary expression, and different from what OP writes, because there is no `else` branche in their code, at least none that we knowof. Moreover, OP already indicated in their question that something like this would not work forthat very reason. Surprised how this answer can get more upvotes than JBD's, which does actually explains it with all the due disclaimers and alternatives.